# Recursive function in Python: Best way to get a list of specific nested items

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a tree of nested dictionaries. This is an small extract, just to give you an idea:

```
db = {
    'compatibility': {
        'style': {
            'path_to_file': 'compatibility/render/style.py',
            'checksum': {
                '0.0.3':'AAA55d796c25ad867bbcb8e0da4e48d17826e6f9fce',
                '0.0.2': '55d796c25ad867bbcb8e0da4e48d17826e6f9fe606',}}},
    'developer': {
        'render': {
            'installation': {
                'path_to_file': 'developer/render/installation.py',
                'checksum': {
                    '0.0.1': 'c1c0d4080e72292710ac1ce942cf59ce0e26319cf3'}},
            'tests': {
                'path_to_file': 'developer/render/test.py',
                'checksum': {
                    '0.0.1': 'e71173ac43ecd949fdb96cfb835abadb877a5233a36b115'}}}}}
```

I want to get a list of all the dictionary modules nested in the tree. That way I would be able to loop the list and test the checksum of each file (Note that the modules could be at different levels like in the example above).

To achieve that, I wrote the following recursive function. I know for a fact that each module has a "path_to_file" and "checksum" keys, so I use that to test if the dict is a module. Note that I had to wrap the recursive function inside another function that holds the list so that the list wouldn't be overwritten each time the recursive function runs.

```
def _get_modules_from_db(dictionary):
    def recursive_find(inner_dictionary):
        for k, v in inner_dictionary.iteritems():
            if (isinstance(v, dict) and
                    not sorted(v.keys()) == ['path_to_file', 'sha512sum']):
                recursive_find(v)
            else:
                leaves.append(v)
    leaves = []
    recursive_find(dictionary)
    return leaves
```

This approach works, however having to wrap the function seems very ugly to me. So, my question for pros at Stack Overflow:

Is there is simpler (or better) approach you would recommend to achieve this without having to wrap the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the only reason you need to wrap the function is because you're making `recursive_find` mutate the `leaves` closure cell in-place instead of `return`ing it. Sometimes that's a useful performance optimization (although just as often it's a pessimization), and sometimes it's just not clear how to do it otherwise, but this time it's trivial:

```
def _get_modules_from_db(dictionary):
    leaves = []
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        if (isinstance(v, dict) and
            not sorted(v.keys()) == ['path_to_file', 'sha512sum']):
            leaves.extend(_get_modules_from_db(v))
        else:
            leaves.append(v)
    return leaves
```

---

For additional improvements: I'd probably turn this into a generator (at least in 3.3+, with `yield from`; in 2.7 I might think twice). And, while we're at it, I'd compare the key-view (in 3.x) or `set(v)` (in 2.x) to a set rather than doing an unnecessary sort (and no reason for `.keys()` with either `set` or `sorted`), and use `!=` rather than `not` and `==`. And, unless there's a good reason to only accept actually `dict` and `dict` subclasses, I'd either duck-type it or use `collections.[abc.]Mapping`. So:

```
def _get_modules_from_db(dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(v, Mapping) and v.keys() != {'path_to_file', 'sha512sum'}:
            yield from _get_modules_from_db(v)
        else:
            yield v
```

Or, alternatively, pull the base cases out, so you can call it directly on a string:

```
def _get_modules_from_db(d):
    if isinstance(d, Mapping) and d.keys() != {'path_to_file', 'sha512sum'}:
        for v in d.values():
            yield from _get_modules_from_db(v)
    else:
        yield d
```

I think that's a little more readable than what you had, and it's 6 lines instead of 11 (although the 2.x version would be 7 lines). But I don't see anything actually wrong with your version.

---

If you're not sure how to turn that 3.3+ code into 2.7/3.2 code:

- Rewrite `yield from eggs` as `for egg in eggs: yield egg`.
- `Mapping` is in `collections`, not `collections.abc`.
- Use `set(v)` instead of `v.keys()`.
- Possibly use `itervalues` instead of `values` (2.x only).

Comment: Upvoted: I rather like the generator - much more elegant than using a list at all.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Sorry; I was actually using _three_ names for the same thing, not just two, because of copying and pasting without testing… it should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, I guess I could use v.viewkeys() in Python 2.7 instead of set(v) right?

Comment: @chrisfromlocalgroup: Yes, that should work; `viewkeys` is just a backport of 3.2's `keys`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem with this approach. You want a recursive function that manipulates some global state - this is a pretty reasonable way to do it (inner functions are not terribly uncommon in Python).

That said, you could add a defaulted argument if you want to avoid the nested function:

```
def _get_modules_from_db(db, leaves=None):
    if leaves is None:
        leaves = []
    if not isinstance(db, dict):
        return leaves

    # Use 'in' check to avoid sorting keys and doing a list compare
    if 'path_to_file' in db and 'checksum' in db:
        leaves.append(db)
    else:
        for v in db.values():
            _get_modules_from_db(v, leaves)

    return leaves
```

Comment: nneonneo, the defaulted argument was what I was looking for originally, Thanks! However @abarnert opened my eyes with the generator recommendation so I am going with his answer!

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, nested functions are nice, but here's a more concise version nonetheless

```
from operator import add

def _get_modules_from_db(db):
  if 'path_to_file' in db and 'sha512sum' in db:
    return [db]
  return reduce(add, (_get_modules_from_db(db[m]) for m in db))
```

Comment: This could potentially fail to stop recursing if it runs into a non-dict object (not in the sample DB, but the OP's code has a defense against it). Also, it iterates over the keys, not the values.

Comment: I already changed the error you mentioned.  The dict described only stores strings--no reason to over generalize the problem.

Comment: `'path_to_file' in db and 'sha512sum' in db` isn't the same thing as those being the _only_ keys. Especially since `db` can be a string; it's somewhat hacky to hide that under the covers by using `in db` as a substring search that you hope never matches, but if you aren't absolutely sure it will never match it's downright wrong.